# msbuild call target on all the project references

Tags: msbuild

I have a requirement to call targets on each of the 'ProjectReferences' for the following hierarchical project structure.

project  A -> project B -> project C

Each project has a target called 'customTarget'. How can define the configuration such that when I call 'customTarget' on project 'A', it triggers 'customTarget' on project 'B' and which indirectly triggers target on 'C'?
Expected target order: C -> B -> A .

Question: How can I configure the above and also make it generic for all project references.

[UPDATE]
I was able to create the chain of target calls using

```
<MSBUILD Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="customTarget" />
```

But this requires me to add the target specification in each project in the project chain even if it's not doing anything.
Would there be any better solution it approach the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your extension target inside a `Directory.Build.props` file:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="customTarget" DependsOnTargets="PrepareProjectReferences">
    <MSBUILD Projects="@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)" 
             Targets="customTarget"
             SkipNonexistentTargets="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

In VS 2017 / MSBuild 15 and higher it will be auto-imported into all projects file below the folder hierarchy.